# Sort dictionary of tuples & take first entry python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, ordereddictionary

I have a long dictionary with this structure:

```
{'key': (integer1, 'string1')}
```

and I want to sort the dictionary by `integer1` & take the first entry.

Here's what I have so far:

```
sorted_by_integer = OrderedDict(sorted(tuple_dict.items(),key=lambda x:x[0], reverse=True))
keys = list(sorted_by_integer)
value = sorted_by_integer[keys[0]]
first_entry = {}
first_entry[keys[0]] = value
```

My question is can I condense...

```
first_entry = {}
first_entry[keys[0]] = value
```

into a one-liner?

Comment: Try `next(iter(sorted_by_integer.items()))`.  Is this output sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

Using a one line expression, you can retrieve the keys of the dictionary in sorted order using the integer in the value as the sort key:

```
s = {'key': (integer1, 'string1')} 
new_data = [a for (a, (b, c)) in sorted(s.items(), key=lambda x: x[-1][0])]
```

Comment: When I try this I only get the keys back in a list.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @e1v1s Yes, this will only give you the sorted keys. If that is not what you are looking for, could please specify exactly?

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
s = {'key': (4, 'string1'), 'key2':(2, 's2'), 'key3':(3, 's3')}
s = dict(sorted(s.items(), key=lambda x: x[-1][0])[:1])
print s
```

**output:**
{'key2': (2, 's2')}

Comment: Is that what you want? @e1v1s